# Generating the report in word format using jasper

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

I am using jasper-reports 4.5.0,spring 3.0.5RELEASE integration to generate the reports.Till now i generated in html,csv,pdf formats.But my client wants the report in word format also(.doc format).How can i generate the report in this .doc format.

Comment: You can try to use [JRDocxExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/ooxml/JRDocxExporter.html) and [JRRtfExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRRtfExporter.html)

Comment: Thank You Alex. org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView like this do we have any class for viewing the report in .doc format

Comment: @Alex if you want to post an answer based on your comment, go ahead and I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just to provide an example code based on Alex's suggestion:

To use JRRtfExporter:

```
protected byte[] exportReportToRtf(JasperPrint jasperPrint) throws JRException{
   JRRtfExporter exporter = new JRRtfExporter();
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();    
   exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
   exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);
   exporter.exportReport(); 
   return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Similarly to us JRDocxExporter:

```
protected byte[] exportReportToRtf(JasperPrint jasperPrint) throws JRException{
   JRDocxExporter exporter = new JRDocxExporter();
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();    
   exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
   exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);
   exporter.exportReport(); 
   return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Edit based on comment:

[Here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/jasperreports/package-summary.html) is the list of the JaperReport Views that the Sprig Fraework provides.

They do not seem to have one specifically for the doc format. You will probably have write your own by extending [AbstractJasperReportsSingleFormatView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/jasperreports/AbstractJasperReportsSingleFormatView.html). It seems you would only need to implement the `createExporter()` method.

```
protected JRExporter createExporter(){
     return new JRDocxExporter();
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your solution.But in my case i can't use like this.Because my flow is exactly like http://chathurangat.blogspot.in/2012/02/jasperreport-with-spring-mvc-fully.html this.I am configuring the view classes to respective view name.Like this is there any predefined view class for rtf or doc format.

Comment: setParameter is deprecated, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/30486677/387454

Answer (score 4):

For future readers setParameter is deprecated and you should use exporters like this:

```
JasperReports 6.1.0

import java.io.File;

//import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRRtfExporter;
//import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRDocxExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleExporterInput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleWriterExporterOutput;

File sourceFile = new File("*.jasper");

JasperPrint jasperPrint = (JasperPrint)JRLoader.loadObject(sourceFile);

File destFile = new File(sourceFile.getParent(), jasperPrint.getName() + ".docx|.rtf");

//JRDocxExporter exporter = new JRDocxExporter();
//JRRtfExporter exporter = new JRRtfExporter();

exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(destFile));

exporter.exportReport();
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on JRDocxExporter, you can extend [AbstractJasperReportsSingleFormatView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/jasperreports/AbstractJasperReportsSingleFormatView.html) :

```
public class CustomJasperWordReportsSingleFormatView extends AbstractJasperReportsSingleFormatView {

@Override
protected void renderReport(JasperPrint populatedReport, Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
     super.renderReport(populatedReport, model, response);
}

@Override
protected JRExporter createExporter() {
    return new JRDocxExporter();
}

@Override
protected boolean useWriter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

and in your `@Controller` you wrap the response with [HttpServletResponseWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) to get the byte array generated by the jasper report:

```
public byte[] getByteArrayWordReport(String jasperViewName, ModelMap model, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws Exception{

View view=xmlViewResolver.resolveViewName(jasperViewName, null);
if(view==null){
     log.error("Report not found:"+jasperViewName);
}
final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    HttpServletResponseWrapper httpServletResponseWrapper=new HttpServletResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse){
           @Override
           public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
                  return new PrintWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);
           }
           public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
                  return new ServletOutputStream() {
                         @Override
                         public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                               byteArrayOutputStream.write(b);                 
                         }
                  };
           }
        @Override
        public void addCookie(Cookie cookie) {
        }
        @Override
        public void addDateHeader(String name, long date) {
        }
        @Override
        public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
        }
        @Override
        public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
        }
        @Override
        public void setIntHeader(String name, int value) {
        }
        @Override
        public void addIntHeader(String name, int value) {
        }
        @Override
        public void setContentLength(int len) {
        }
        @Override
        public void setContentType(String type) {
        }
    };
    view.render(model, httpServletRequest, httpServletResponseWrapper);
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

After that you have the byte array representing the Word Document.